# The toddler is holding a lego on his hand

Tags: vocabulary

> The toddler is **holding** a lego on his hand.
>   The toddler is **grasping** a lego on his hand.

Which word is more commonly used if a toddler is taking a lego (small piece) in his hand?

Comment: I guess "a lego" wouldn't surprise me, but in my speech it's always "a lego piece", "a lego block", "a piece of lego", "a block", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly for this context, I'll answer it in a *medical way!* BTW, it's 'in his hand'.

> The toddler is *holding* a lego in his hand

That's because *[grasping](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/grasp)* comes from your **willingness and power.** If you as an adult grasp my hand, it'll be difficult for me to take my hand off but it is not that in the toddler's case.

The toddler has *involuntary flexes and reflexes* at that age so it's *holding* and not *actually grasping.*

Comment: "In his hand" is perfectly correct and the usual way to say it. "In hand" has a completely different usage and in this context would sound robotic and weird.

Comment: @CocoPop I meant 'in his hand' only but wrote it in a general way. Corrected.

Comment: The answer is correct in that holding is the more common word here, but it is equally possible and correct to use grasp. Grasping doesn't necessarily require willingness, more simply power or tightness and babies can certainly grasp. "The baby grasped my finger." isn't at all unusual.

Comment: @DavidHall when used for babies/kids, I think *grasp* is used more commonly for their memory/learning power -grasping power. When a baby starts taking things and retain it, we generally used *holding*. I mean as a medical person, I use it.